# Get coordinates of app icon in view pager of main screen/home screen programatically?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to animate the app icon on start of the app but how can i get exact position of icon on home screen/main screen but i don't know whether its possible or not.I know for widget its possible by getIntent().getSourceBounds() but for app icon, i didn't find anything.Is there any default api available to get this information and if yes will it work on any device which is custom like HTC sense or samsung?

I have searched about it a lot but didn't get any useful information.Ifanyone has any idea about this please let me know?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be possible, since the Launcher aka HomwScreen is a own application which can be different on differnt devices. Even if you could get the position of the Launcher icon on the Homescreen, you still wouldn't be able to animate anything because there is no callback or anything that notifies you when the launcher icon is clicked.

Comment: Ok strange! but how come we get the coordinates of widgets by getIntent().getSourceBounds() there must be an api for this.

Comment: @AbsGuy even if there is, how would you animate the icon using these coordinates?